# Confusion over the use of the pin (^) operator

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm looking at some Elixir code that looks like this:

```
  @to_preload [
    :last_modified_by,
    change_request: [application: [:app_definition]],
    comments: [:user]
  ]

  def preload(query) do
    preload(query, ^@to_preload)
  end
```

I believe the call `preload(query, ^@to_preload)` is actually to the [Query.preload/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3) macro as the file has an `import Ecto.Query`.

So my question is, what exactly is the `^` doing in front of the module attribute `@to_preload` in that call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right. `preload` there is referring to `Ecto.Query.preload/3`. From Ecto's docs:

> When writing a query, you are inside Ecto's query syntax. In order to access params values or invoke Elixir functions, you need to use the ^ operator, which is overloaded by Ecto

This is why the pin operator (`^`) is being used. You need to use it so that the module attribute can be interpolated.

If you were to write the query without using the pin operator, you would get the following error:

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) `@to_preload` is not a valid preload expression.
preload expects an atom, a list of atoms or a keyword list with more preloads as
values. Use ^ on the outermost preload to interpolate a value
```

So, the code you shared would be equivalent to:

```rb
def preload(query) do
  preload(query, [
    :last_modified_by,
    change_request: [application: [:app_definition]],
    comments: [:user]
  ])
end
```

There's actually [an example in preload's documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#preload/3-preload-queries) using the pin operator. It could be confusing that the function that is being defined is called `preload` as well. However, because of the arity, there's no confusion, since Ecto.Query's preload could take 2 or 3 arguments, whereas the one defined here only takes 1.